How to repair or replace rotten studs
Greeting All! I just got a tough job to do and would need your advice. The studs under the window are rotted. From left to right, the second stud is partially rotted. Its right side is soft. The third one (only a small tip left) and the horizontal stud are very bad. The two nails already fell out after removing the rotten wood. Due to the locations of the window and the bathtub, I cannot open the wall from the inside. Do I need to open the wall from the outside to repair them? If so, it's beyond my ability to fix them myself. So, what kind of contractor should I hire?
The horizontal stud is supposed to rest on the third vertical stud. But, they don’t seem to support anything. If I don’t repair or replace the them, would it result in more damages?
Any suggestions are appreciated.




I hate to say it, but this is usually the precursor to a full bathroom reno. Even if it’s easy to replace the studs from the back, the tiled surface won’t be adequately supported, which will lead to cracks/ leakage/ rot. A good general contractor is who you need.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, that is good for an answer. An added note. Being a window opening all the structural is in the header over the window and the studs on either side of the window opening. Fortunately the jack stud on this side that is actually supporting the header looks good according to what I see in the picture. The stud with the rotted top are what is called "cripples" non structural framing that only holds the window and finish materials. I can't say what is going on down below the tub since water always wants to go down. That said, this would warrant a tear out in given time.

Thank you @AloysiusDefenestrate and @Jack! Both of your comments are very helpful. I actually feel a bit relief by Jack's comment about "cripples" framing :-).

Do you have basement or crawl space under the tub? You might consider cutting away some of the subfloor under the tub to be able to see the framing and its condition. (The tub drain is an excellent landmark for positioning.)

@AloysiusDefenestrate, thank you again. This is definitely a good hint. The location is on the 2nd floor. Underneath the bathtub is my laundry room on the main floor. I think if I remove some insulation from the opening, I would be able to see a little bit more inside using an endoscope which I have.

I have not fixed the rotted studs yet, but I found the cause of rot. The window has two sections. The upper section is half round and has its own sill. The sill slopes down towards inside to meet the glass panel where caulk failed long time ago. It's unbelievable.
